# What is "seoi zi" for 好玩?

Tags: cantonese

Watching《金玉滿堂》recently where a character said something on the lines of:

> seoi m seoi zi?

If I were to hazard a guess I would think it would be written something like: 衰唔衰志？The Mandarin subtitles gave the translation:

> 好不好玩？

I was unable to find anything resembling "seoi zi" in my Cantonese dictionaries. Perhaps the inital on "seoi" is wrong.

Ideas?

Comment: Just a guess: could be ceoi m ceoi zi 趣唔趣緻

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it is actually "ceoi m ceoi zi" 趣唔[趣緻](https://yue.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%B6%A3%E7%B7%BB).

趣緻 in Cantonese can mean 好玩、interesting, lovely.